# filteringSelect with multichecked

Tags: widget, dojo, dijit.form

is there any ready widget like that?
If not, can I combine the dijit filteringSelect with dojox multichecked?
if not, is it easy to create one of my own or has any one started doing this? it's so necessary for my project.

Answer (score 1):

There is no widget like that as far as I know (the multichecked widget itself is not even a standard widget, since it's a part from DojoX).

About your question of combining both. I don't think that will be easy, because the `dijit/form/FilteringSelect` does not use a `<select>` as widget and I don't think they're made to be ran together.

And the answer to your last question: it all depends on what functionality you exactly need. A `dijit/form/FilteringSelect` only allows you to select 1 value (it's a textbox with a dropdown in fact, and a textbox can only have 1 value).

If you want to create a variant with radio buttons, then that is possible, but it is not an easy job. The multichecked is working with a simple DOM node, however, the `dijit/form/FilteringSelect` offers a lot more things like autocomplete, stores, ... . To make your widget work, you need to listen to all these events and adapt yuur radio buttons to it.

I made a simple example that is only displaying radio buttons for each item in the filtering select, the code can be seen at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/D5Xn8/). However, it does not react to changes, that's a part that you will have to implement.

Comment: thanks dimitri for the detailed answer.
although what I need is a checkbox not radio buttons.
I think I will need to extend the filtering select widget with a new rendered labels.